# como mostrar Sim e Não no lugar de 0 e 1 no java?

Tags: java, html, table

Estou travado nesse problema, preciso mostrar Sim e Não na tabela do xhtml no lugar de 0 e 1, o tipo de retorno no get e set é BigDecimal e as formas que tentei sempre acabam quebrando ou nem rodando por conta de querer colocar um String no lugar, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

esse é o método para gravar os dados na tabela do front: (a mudança que eu quero fazer seria no `record[3]`)

```
private ContaFornecedorVO getContaFornecedor(Object[] record) {
    
    String validar;
    ContaFornecedorVO vo = new ContaFornecedorVO();
    vo.setCodigoConta(((BigDecimal) record[0]).longValue());
    vo.setDsConta((String) record[1]);
    vo.setNrContaSap((BigDecimal) (record[2]));
    vo.setFlagAbatimentoOrigem((BigDecimal) (record[3]));   

    return vo;
}
```

o tipo de dado no VO:

```
private BigDecimal flagAbatimentoOrigem;
```

a forma que a coluna está no front:

```
<p:column id="flag" style="width:50px" styleClass="columnRight">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Flag Abatimento" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{tbl.flagAbatimentoOrigem}" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visto que as possibilidades de exibição são para *Sim* ou *Não*, você poderia colocar dois `outputText` variando a exibição deles por meio do atributo `rendered` da seguinte forma:

```
  <p:column id="flag" style="width:50px" styleClass="columnRight">
                                            <f:facet name="header">
                                                <h:outputText value="Flag Abatimento" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="Sim" rendered="#{tbl.flagAbatimentoOrigem == 1}"/>
                                            <h:outputText value="Não" rendered="#{tbl.flagAbatimentoOrigem == 0}"/>
                                        </p:column>
```

Uma forma mais elaborada de solucionar seria com a utilização de `converter`, mas para a situação não acharia necessário.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!! estava tentando fazer isso no backend a uns 2 dias e tinha travado, bigDecimal é meio chato de trabalhar, funcionou perfeitamente!!